# Function changes my string to a completly different value

Tags: javascript, regex

I need your help,

I have the following function below. What is happening, is that when it is executed it changes my native file number (x) to XAI-2012-402518 when all it is supposed to is add a -2 at the end and then increment it every single time after that.

The desired result is: `XAI-2012-402517-2` and not `XAI-2012-402518`

Regularly, without any dashes in the string, it works just fine, but I think the function is confusing the dashes.

Other examples are:

```
filenumber -> filenumber-2
filenumber2 -> filenumber-3
XAI-2012-402517 -> XAI-2012-402517-2
XAI-2012-402517-2 -> XAI-2012-402517-3
XAI-2012-402517-3 -> XAI-2012-402517-4
```

ect.

```
function test2(){ 
    var x = "XAI-2012-402517"

    x = x.replace(/^(.+?)(-\d+)?$/, function(a,b,c) { return c ? b+(c-1) : a+'-2'; } );

    alert(x)
}
```

Comment: If your 'c' needs to be from 3rd dash '-' then change the regex to match the digit after 3 dashes.

Comment: Given that some of your filenames end with a `-\d+` already, you need additional rules to distinguish between a file version number and a part of the filename itself. E.g. Will there always be no more than 2 dashes? Will the version never be more than 1 digit? etc. Otherwise there is an inherent ambiguity to your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function works exactly right. You have an algorithm "capture a digit that comes after the last dash and increase it by one".
In "XAI-2012-402517", the digit that comes after the dash is 402517 and therefore it needs to be incremented.

In order to fix this, you need to put a limitation to the condition. For example you may wish to increase only the last digit after dash if it is less than 100:

```
    function test2(x){ 
            x = x.replace(/^(.+?)(-\d{0,2})?$/, function(a,b,c) { 
            return c ? b+(c-1) : a+'-2'; } );
            console.log(x)
    }
    test2("XAI-2012-402517") //XAI-2012-402517-2
    test2("XAI-2012-402517-2") //XAI-2012-402517-3
```